# Как зарегистрировать, удалить и найти dll в реестре windows используя c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, com

Как зарегистрировать, отменить регистрацию или получить информацию о dll в реестре windows используя c++?

Comment: использовать regsvr32?

Comment: @KoVadim, мне необходимо сделать это программно

Comment: можно посмотреть, как это сделано в reactOS https://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/dcf/regsvr32_8c_source.html